Content not from webpack is served from '/app' directory (Docker / Webpack)
I'm using Webpack configuration with docker.
Everything working well as development step. However this is not working for my preproduction and production step. The difference between these steps is that I copy past my entire repository when it is the development step and only the build file when it is preproduction/production step.
Why ? Because I want to optimise the space on my server.
There is my docker file configuration:
FROM node:alpine AS base
USER root
WORKDIR /app
COPY frontend/package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g serve

FROM base AS development
COPY frontend /app/
RUN npm run build:development

FROM base AS preproduction
COPY frontend/build /app/build
COPY frontend/public /app/public
COPY frontend/webpack.config.js /app/
COPY frontend/env /app/env

FROM base AS production
COPY frontend/build /app/build
COPY frontend/public /app/public
COPY frontend/webpack.config.js /app/
COPY frontend/env /app/env

As you can see above, only build file is paste to the container for preproduction and production in the application repository "app" (The build is done in a jenkins pipeline before running the dockerfile).
This my webpack configuration:
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = () => {
  console.info("Environment: ", process.env.NODE_ENV);
  return {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.tsx"),
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
      filename: "bundle.js",
      assetModuleFilename: "assets/[name][ext]",
    },
    devServer: {
      compress: true,
      port: 3000,
      static: __dirname,
      historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, `./env/.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`),
        systemvars: true,
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html"),
        filename: "index.html",
        favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
        manifest: "./public/manifest.json",
        inject: "body",
      }),
    ],
    ...
}

And this my package.json script command, I'm running:
"cleanBuild": "rm -rf build/* && cp public/index.html build/index.html",
"build:preproduction": "npm run cleanBuild && NODE_ENV=preproduction webpack --mode production",
"start:preproduction": "NODE_ENV=preproduction webpack serve --mode production --port 3000 --allowed-hosts all",

So, does anyone know if it is mandatory to have the src file to be present in the app folder in order to have webpack working ?
If not, how can I manage it or solve my issue ?

You almost certainly need the src tree to run the build:preproduction step; I'd assume you don't for the start:preproduction step though.  I'd also consider copying the built files to a final stage based on nginx so you don't need Node at all in the final image, particularly if optimizing for space is your goal.

Looks like I'm having the same issue with development step, but the historyApiFallback is redirecting to "/". So I would say the issue is coming from: "static: __dirname", but after having modified it to "static: path.resolve(__dirname, "build")" where the index.html is nested with the bundle.js inserted in it, I'm still having the same error with different path returned: "Content not from webpack is served from '/app/build' directory".

What specific actions are you taking to produce these errors?  Do they occur when building an image, or running a container?  If running, do you overwrite the image content with volume mounts?

It happens when running the container, I removed the volume attached, And I'm having the same behaviour.

What exactly are you running?  The Dockerfile doesn't seem to have a CMD, so it's not obvious what might be happening.

There is a docker-compose file with the command "npm run start:${TARGET}". Everything start as expected.

In order to solve the issue, I Copy paste the SRC file which is mandatory in order to let webpack run properly.
